# SonarTsPlugin is not considering rules

Tags: typescript, jenkins, sonarqube, measurement, tslint

For an Angular2 project I want to run measurements on it. I'm very new to such things.

I integrated the [SonarTsPlugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin) to the SonarQube. But for some reasons the rules are not going to apply on the sourcecode. There were absolutely no rule break according to the report. So I got suspicious and deliberately breached the following rule:

> == and != must not be used - use === or !== instead

with the following line of code:

```
    if (res.statusCode == 0) {

      //do something

    } else if (res.statusCode == -1) {

      //do something different

    };
```

I can see that SonarQube is correctly considering the corresponding TypeScript file. So I'd expect that there would be at least one rule breach. Furthermore, I use Jenkins to run the measurements but I don't believe that the mistake is there. The output says that it ran successfully

My **sonar-project.properties** looks like this:

```
sonar.projectKey=my.project
sonar.projectName=my-project
sonar.projectVersion=0.0.1-Snapshot
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources={ProjectPath}/ng-cli/src/app
sonar.exclusions={ProjectPath}/ng-cli/node_modules/**, 20_sourcecode/DDS_Client/ng-cli/src/app/*.spec.ts
sonar.tests={ProjectPath}/ng-cli/src/app
sonar.test.inclusions={ProjectPath}/ng-cli/src/app/*.spec.ts
sonar.ts.tslint.configPath={ProjectPath}/ng-cli/tslint.json
```

I have no custom rules. In SonarQube I have defined the path to TSLint:

```
{Path}/tslint/bin/tslint
```

I checked the paths, they should be okay (unless I'm misunderstanding where to refer).

I'm using:

- *SonarQube*: 5.6.5
- *SonarTsPlugin:* v1.1.0-RC1
- *tslint:* 4.3.0
- *Jenkins:* 1.598 (if necessary)

Is there something I missed to configure or any other advise?

**Edit:**
I tested it with a more obvious rule breach:

> Enforcing a default case in switch statements

and added the following line of code:

```
var someString: string = "1";
switch (someString) {
   case "1":
      /* code */
      break;
}
```

SonarQube recognizes those new lines but is not reporting a rule breach here.

Comment: Maintainer of the plugin here - things to check:

 - Are the rules enabled in your quality profile?
 - If you run the Scanner with the -X flag, do you see any diagnostic output indicating issues?
- If you run the command line to tslint that appears in the log file after using the -X flag, do you see issues reported?